# What is the difference between the Hopkinson's test and the Swinburne's test for a DC motor/generator?

Tags: efficiency, testing

If both are used to calculate the efficiency for a DC motor/generator, then why don't we just use the Swinburne's test? For example it has a easier circuit. Is there (maybe) an advantage of one test over the other?

Comment: Did you find anything significant during your research? It's not my area, but a quick Google found descriptions of both tests along with lists of advantages and disadvantages. For example [Hopkinson here](http://www.electrical4u.com/hopkinsons-test/) and [Swinburne here](http://www.electrical4u.com/swinburnes-test-of-dc-machine/) - scroll to the bottom for the pros/cons. The main difference to my untrained eye is that Hopkinson's is performed under full load, while Swinburne's isn't. Does that matter? You tell me :-)

Comment: @Roger Rowland At full load more power is lost than that at no-load?

Comment: I can only read what's in those links - like I said, this is not my area. If you can't figure out anything useful from what I posted, you'll have to wait for an expert to come along. I'm really just making sure you've don't sufficient research yourself before asking, otherwise you might not get the best response.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the notable differences between Hopkinson's and Swinburne's test include:

1. In Hopkinson's test we need a pair of both motor and a generator whereas in Swinburne's we need only one.
2. The temperature rise can be observed in Hopkinson's test because this test is done under full load conditions but since Swinburne's test is done in no-load conditions, we cannot observe the temperature rise.